# How can mysql not handle two insert request called at same time?

Tags: php, mysql, slim

I have created rest api in php (slim framework with mysql as database) for keeping records of multiple android app's users, So when our app is opened by user it calls register api and sends parameters to trigger insert or update operation

Here's structure for `users` table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `api_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `device_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `device_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `device_model` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `device_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `device_memory` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `device_os` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_access` int(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2130346 ;
```

before inserting record api checks if user already present in users table using two parameters app_code & device_id
If its present then just update user's last_access(and device_token if its different than previous one) fields and return flag:2(user already exist)
update query looks like this

```
UPDATE users SET device_token='asadiwp0qidkqwdpkpka2',last_access='1498912512' WHERE id = '2132079'
```

and if user is not present return flag:1(new user). 
mysql insert query looks like this

```
"INSERT INTO users(app_code, api_key, device_id, device_token,device_model, device_name, device_memory, device_os, last_access) values('YEVZ6I', 'b005e8a2babe0163a8eb4bfb2fe87b78', '66BBEG13B5F2G3EG', 'asadiwp0qidkqwdpkpka','Moto E3', 'Motorola E3 Power', '2GB', 'M', '1498912256')"
```

Where mendatory parameters are "app_code, api_key, device_id, device_token".

Now problem is that currently i am getting register request two times from same device at the same time same second, So mysql insert statement is being called twice at the same time and same user record is inserted twice as a new user, it duplicates record.

Comment: Create a unique index for device_id, that prevents duplictes (second insert will fail, with a key violation error). But you should find the reason for sending twice.

Comment: sorry @BitAccesser , i forgot to mention that users table keeps record of multiple application's users, so cannot apply index on device_id.

Comment: you should make the "app_code, api_key, device_id, device_token" unique so that insertion will no happen for the same device again.

Comment: I agree with @danielad

Comment: app_code changes app wise so cant make it unique for each records, as there are multiple apps cannot make device_id unique because user can use multiple apps.

Comment: you need to add and extra layer of checking this process before its even saved - you make sure you dont have all this same app...id exist or not. Then you insert or you just may be update

Comment: that extra layer is already there, i mentioned in my question the update query. @danielad

Comment: then how come the duplicates ??

Comment: insert request being called at same time that's why.

Comment: finally problem solved, applied multiple column index on app_code & device_id.  found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389780/php-mysql-prevent-duplicate-entries-over-multiple-columns   thank you everyone for helping me out.